# Using rugarch in python to succesfully create an ARMAX-ARCH model

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Hello dear stackoverflow readers (and hopefully commenters),

I am trying to create an ARMAX-ARCH model in python. However I found that the libraries in Pyton are lacking. Doing a LOT of googling I found a working solution for a zero-mean ARCH model here on stackoverflow, however when I tried to adjust it to ARMAX I ran into some difficulties. I am a complete R (and python) beginner so I'm truly stuck.

In the code below I create a temporary dataframe, based on stock prices given to my arch model object (self.endogenous in this case). I then transform the raw stock prices into log returns. However at the 'mean_model=robjects.r('list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), external.regressors = self.exogenous)') step is where the problems are at. If I run this code I get the following error message:

**rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in (function (expr, envir = parent.frame(), enclos = if (is.list(envir) ||  : object 'self.exogenous' not found**

So it would seem that either I don't convert my exogenous variable properly or I don't use the right notation. If I remove the external.regressor part my code works perfectly.
Basicly my question boils down to how I should implement the exogenous part of my mean_process into rugarch.

Thank you in advance!

```
def fit_arch_model(self):

        df = DataFrame(columns=['daily_returns', 'monthly_std', 'annual_vol'])

        df['daily_returns'] = np.log(self.endogenous['Close']).diff()  # Daily log returns
        df['monthly_std'] = df['daily_returns'].rolling(21).std()  # Standard deviation across trading month
        df['annual_vol'] = df['monthly_std'] * np.sqrt(252)  # Convert monthly standard devation to annualized volatility

        df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
        forecast_horizon= 30
        # Initialize R GARCH model
        rugarch = importr('rugarch', lib_loc="C:/Users/Ruben/Documents/R/win-library/3.6")


        garch_spec = rugarch.ugarchspec(
            mean_model=robjects.r('list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), external.regressors = self.exogenous)'),
            variance_model=robjects.r('list(garchOrder=c(1,1))'),
            distribution_model='std')
        # Used to convert training set to R list for model input
        numpy2ri.activate()
        # Train R GARCH model on returns as %
        garch_fitted = rugarch.ugarchfit(
            spec=garch_spec,
            data=df['daily_returns'].values * 100,
            out_sample=forecast_horizon
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and solved it creating a work around.
I created a R function and then used it to fit the model and generate forecast.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FloatVector

# X is a Panda Series that contains the returns I want to fit the model
returns = FloatVector(X.values)   

robjects.r("""  
     f <- function (X) {
     spec = ugarchspec(
     variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)),
     mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1, 1), include.mean=T),
     distribution.model="sged"
     ) 

     fit = tryCatch(
     ugarchfit(
     spec, X, solver = 'hybrid'
     ), error=function(e) e, warning=function(w) w
     )  
     fore = ugarchforecast(fit, n.ahead=1)
     ind = fore@forecast$seriesFor
     ind
     }""")

r_f = robjects.globalenv['f']
fore = r_f(returns)

fore
R object with classes: ('matrix',) mapped to:
<Matrix - Python:0x0000018D6760CB08 / R:0x0000018D76890AD0>
[0.001222]
```

Hope this can help with your problem!